# Adding and subtracting strings and characters in C

Tags: c, string, char

I saw a question which had code snippet in C like this

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char s[] = "MANIPAL2022";
    printf("%s", s+s[4]-s[3]);

    return 0;
}
```

which returned:

```
2022
```

I am not able to understand what is being done here and how is the adding of characters showing these values.

Moreover a string of the same length like `WESTHAM2022` returned nothing

I tried to understand the pattern for this and for `char s[] = "WESTHAM2022" printf("%s", s+s[5]-s[3]);`
The compiler returned some garbage value `!)�U`

And for

```
char s[] = "WESTHAM2022";
    printf("%s", s+s[2]-s[3]);
```

it returned `9WESTHAM2022`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 s+s[4]-s[3]
="MANIPAL2022"+'P'-'I'
="MANIPAL2022"+80-73
="MANIPAL2022"+7
="2022"
```

Here the last step is how pointer works.

With `s = "WESTHAM2022"`, `s+s[5]-s[3]` = `s-19`, pointing at an undefined area, thus it can return anything or crash

Comment: Yes I get it now. But for ```WESTHAM2022``` and ```s+s[2]-s[3]```, I should get  ```WESTHAM2022 + S -T = WESTHAM2022 + 83 - 84 = WESTHAM2022-1``` so why does this return ```9WESTHAM2022```.

Comment: I think you could be more clear that `s` is a _pointer_ and `s[2]` is an _integer value_. Adding `7` to `"MANIPAL2020"` changes the pointer from the first character to the eighth.

Comment: @Dúthomhas I understood that adding 7 moves the pointer 7 places ahead but thank you for your concern.

Comment: @ZeusLegend `"9WESTHAM2022"+1` = `"WESTHAM2022"` and therefore `"WESTHAM2022"-1` can be `"9WESTHAM2022"`. Yet it is also possible to result in `"$WESTHAM2022"`, `""`(actually `"\0WESTHAM2022"`) or crash

Comment: @ZeusLegend what would you expect to get for `"WESTHAM2022"-1`? Accessing an array outside of its bounds causes undefined behaviour